# How to allow regular expression to return empty string

Tags: python, regex

I have a series of text files to parse which may or may not contain any one of a collection of headers, and then lines of data or comment below that header. All header groups are preceded by a double line break.

I am seeking a regular expression that will return an empty string if it sees a header followed immediately by a double line break. I need to differentiate whether a document has that header with no content, or does not have that header at all.

For example, here are portions of two documents:

```
Dogs
Spaniel
Beagle

Birds
Parrot
```

and

```
Dogs

Amphibians
Frogs
Salamanders
```

I would like a regex that would return `Spaniel\nBeagle` in the first document, and an empty string for the second.

The closest I have been able to find is (in Python syntax) `expr = re.compile("Dogs(.+?|)?\n\n, re.DOTALL)`. This returns the correct value for the first, but in the second case it returns `\n\nAmphibians\nFrogs\nSalamanders`. The second question mark and the pipe do not do what I had hoped.

I am handling this by program logic right now, searching for `Dogs\n\n` and only returning contents if that regex is not found, but it is unsatisfying because nothing beats the feeling of a single regular expression doing the job.

So: is there a regex that will match the second document, and return `""`?

Comment: Use: `expr = re.compile(r'Dogs.*\n\n')`

Comment: Good lord, was I ever overthinking it. Thank you!

Comment: "nothing beats the feeling of a single regular expression doing the job.": It's a naive belief.

Comment: Fair enough. 'Elegantly', perhaps I should have added.

Comment: If you use `re.compile(r'Dogs.*\n\n', re.S)` and you have a `Dogs`  with 2 linebreaks right after and then a document having megabytes of data, the regex might time out, or be extremely slow due to backtracking. Avoid using `.*` if you have long texts. Use [`(?m)^Dogs(.*(?:\n(?!\n).*)*)`](https://regex101.com/r/k8azag/2) pattern (no DOTALL modifier).

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**

Your [`Dogs(.+?|)?\n\n`](https://regex101.com/r/WhAClH/1) pattern matches the word `Dogs` anywhere in the document, then tries to *optionally* (as there is an empty alternative `|)`) match any *1 or more* (due to `+?` quantifier) characters, but as few as possible (since `+?` is a *lazy* quantifier), up to the first 2 newlines.

That means, the regex either matches `Dogs` only if there are no double newline symbols somewhere further in the text, or it will grab any text there is up to the first double newline symbols, because the `.+?` will consume 1 newline, and the `\n\n` pattern part will not be able to find the 2 newlines after `Dogs`.

**Solution**

You may use a `*?` quantifier instead of `+?` one to allow matching *zero or more* characters. The [`Dogs(.*?)\n\n`](https://regex101.com/r/WhAClH/2) will find `Dogs`, any 0+ chars as few as possible, up to the first `\n\n`, even those that appear right after `Dogs`.

**Optimization**:

If you process very long strings, and if the `Dogs` appear at the beginning of a line, you may use an unrolled regex since `.*?` is known to slow regex execution with longer inputs.

Use

```
expr = re.compile(r"^Dogs(.*(?:\n(?!\n).*)*)", re.MULTILINE)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/k8azag/3)

Basically, it will match

- `^`  - start of a line
- `Dogs`  - `Dogs` substring
- `(.*(?:\n(?!\n).*)*)` - Group 1 capturing:

  - `.*` - zero or more chars other than linebreak chars (as the `re.DOTALL` modifier is not used)
  - `(?:\n(?!\n).*)*` - zero or more sequences of:

    - `\n(?!\n)` - a newline not followed with another newline
    - `.*` - zero or more chars other than linebreak chars